# Having trouble converting NSString containing number won't convert to integer

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, int

I have the following line of code:

```
NSString *dMidiInfo = [object valueForKey:@"midiInformation"];
```

That returns this from the debugger:

{type = immutable, count = 1, capacity = 3, pairs = (
    3 : {contents = "192"}

from this log statement `NSLog(@"this is the string:  %@",dMidiInfo);`

I get this :
{(
    192
)}

but when this line executes:

```
firstByteB = [dMidiInfo intValue];
```

I get this error:

[NSCFSet intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176f10

Are the brackets messing my code up?

After some additional troubleshooting:
This code actually worked with a fetch request with this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Effect" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

This returned all of the entities, I was trying to return one entity so I switched to this:

NSArray *currentSelSong = [sillySongs selectedObjects];
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [currentSelSong valueForKey:@"songToEffect"];

It seems that the selectedObjects adds the brackets

Comment: I believe that `object`'s `midiInformation` property is actually an `NSSet` instance, not an `NSString`

Comment: @Jacob, surely that's an answer rather than a comment. Why did you delete the answer?

Comment: @paxdiablo Undeleted. Thanks! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `object`'s `midiInformation` property is actually an `NSSet` instance, not an `NSString`.

Comment: I think that this is what you guys were getting at:

NSSet * midiSecondByte = [object valueForKey:@"midiSecondByte"];
  NSString *secIntString = [midiSecondByte anyObject];
  secondByteB = [secIntString intValue];

And this is what ended up working!  Thanks a ton

Loren